# Does a license allow or permit?

Tags: american-english

In US English should I say

> You have already activated more sites than your license allows

Or

> You have already activated more sites than your license permits

Comment: The verbs "allow" and "permit" mean the same thing, but you need to say "allows" or "permits".

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/allow-permit-or-let

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some degree, *'permits'* sounds a wee bit more formal. Given the formality of the sentence, I would suggest *'permits'*. But then again, you were specific about **AmE**, and a little digging showed that the use of *'allows'* is more widespread in American literature.

This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=license+allows%2Clicense+permits&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicense%20allows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicense%20permits%3B%2Cc0) on *'license allows'* vs *'license permits'* clearly shows that the usage of *'allows'* is far more extensive.

[image]

**Note:** The comparison has been done over books written in AmE.

Comment: I can't edit because it's too minor, but you might want to change the body of your post so that  your spelling of "license" is consistent (even though "licence" is OK in the UK)